# Get first and last day from .csv with VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, csv

I have two properties

```
Property FirstDayOfCsv As String
Property LastDayOfCsv As String
```

I want that properties obtains min and max values from parsed csv file. Values are days in "dd" format from date column. Now my code looks like this:

```
Dim csv As String() = IO.File.ReadAllLines("my.csv").Skip(1).ToArray
For Each line In csv
            Dim col = line.Split(";"c)
            Dim days As Date = col(2)
            FirstDayOfCsv = days.ToString("dd").Min
            LastDayOfCsv = days.ToString("dd").Max
Next
```

Unfortunately Min and Max doesn't return values, which I need and I'm stucking here. How to get them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option that you have is to add the values to a collection, but converting the String values to Integer values first. Then once you're finished iterating over the lines you would call Min/Max.

```vb
Dim csv = IO.File.ReadAllLines("my.csv").Skip(1).ToArray()
Dim everyday = New List(Of Integer)()
For Each line In csv
    Dim col = line.Split(";"c)
    Dim days = col(2)
    Dim daysAsInt As Integer
    If (Integer.TryParse(days, daysAsInt)) Then
        everyday.Add(daysAsInt)
    End If
Next

FirstDayOfCsv = everyday.Min()
LastDayOfCsv = everyday.Max()
```